Getting an nginx server work both on a domain and a subdomain (one of them static and the other served from a Next JS app)
I have an Ubuntu 24.10 Digitalocean VPS and I want to host two websites using Nginx.
One is website-name.com where I want to host a static export of a Next JS website whose contents I have copied to the /var/www/out folder and the other is subdomain.website-name.com where I want to host a Next JS application that is running on localhost:3000.
In the folder /etc/nginx/sites-available/, I have a configuration file called myapp which acts as a proxy for localhost:3000. This configuration file is as follows:
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/s;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.website-name.com;

    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name subdomain.website-name.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website-name.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website-name.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    # Enable rate limiting
    limit_req zone=mylimit burst=20 nodelay;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        # Disable buffering for streaming support
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Buffering no;
    }
}

I have another configuration file in the folder /etc/nginx/sites-available/ called website-name.com to serve the static website whose contents are available in the /var/www/out folder. This configuration file is as follows:
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name website-name.com;

  root /var/www/out;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  location = /404.html {
      internal;
  }
}

I got this config from the documentation page of Next JS.
Instead of getting the static website on the url https://website-name.com, I am getting the Next JS app running on localhost:3000.
On the url https://subdomain.website-name.com I am getting the Next JS app correctly as required.
I am not able to figure out what's going wrong. Can anyone please help?
Note: I have used certbot to expand the certificate for website-name.com to subdomain.website-name.com as well (I have followed the answer of this question for that). I have also created an A record for subdomain.website-name.com.

The problem is that I haven't configured the static website to use SSL. Hence I can see the static site only on the url http://website-name.com not on the https url.

In your configuration files, there is a server block listening on port 443 (https) for subdomain.example.com but not for example.com.
When Nginx receives a request to https://example.com, it checks all the server blocks listening on port 443 for a matching server_name.
Finding no match, it will use the default server for port 443 (which in this case is the only server listening on port 443.

You need to define a server block for https://example.com, for example:
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website-name.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website-name.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/out;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  location = /404.html {
      internal;
  }
}

